# Jest encountered an unexpected token This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript

Tags: angular, d3.js, jestjs

Facing issue while running Jest test cases in combination of D3 with Jest and angular.

Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

D:\Git\Sept-2021\repo\node_modules\d3-geo\node_modules\d3-array\src\index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export {default as bisect, bisectRight, bisectLeft, bisectCenter} from "./bisect.js";
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1350:14)
  at ../../node_modules/d3-geo/dist/d3-geo.js:3:81
  at Object.<anonymous> (../../node_modules/d3-geo/dist/d3-geo.js:6:2)
```

Please suggest D3 configuration with Jest and AnguarJS.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following to my **jest.config.js** file solved the issue when using d3 modules:

```js
{
// An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!d3-(array|format))'
  ]
}
```

so I guess that adding the **d3-geo** module to the ignore pattern array should solve it

```js
{
// An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths, matched files will skip transformation
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/(?!d3-(array|format|geo))'
  ]
}
```